# How to use own components library with LexicalJS

Tags: reactjs, lexicaljs

Trying to understand how to use own components library instead of rendering certain html elements.

If we take the mentions plugin (https://lexical.dev/docs/demos/plugins/mentions) how could we render e.g. our own Text functional component instead of creating a dom element with `const dom = super.createDOM(config);`